# Best way to write this query? Several JOINS

Tags: mysql

I have this query (below) while it does work I am wondering if it is the best as it will be going against thousands of records. I will try to explain the best I can.

```
SELECT items.*, 
       p.file                        AS item_pic, 
       i_f.id                        AS favorite_id, 
       COALESCE(f.favorite_count, 0) AS favorite_count, 
       COALESCE(b.num_buys, 0)       AS num_buys, 
       COALESCE(c.comment_count, 0)  AS comment_count 
FROM   items i 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT file, 
                          item_id 
                   FROM   item_pics 
                   ORDER  BY item_pics.id ASC) AS p 
               ON p.item_id = i.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS favorite_count, 
                         item_id 
                  FROM   item_favorites 
                  GROUP  BY item_id) AS f 
              ON f.item_id = i.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_buys, 
                         item_id 
                  FROM   purchases 
                  GROUP  BY item_id) AS b 
              ON b.item_id = i.id 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS comment_count, 
                         item_id 
                  FROM   comments 
                  GROUP  BY item_id) AS c 
              ON c.item_id = i.id 
       LEFT JOIN item_favorites AS i_f 
              ON i.id = i_f.item_id 
                 AND i_f.userid = '14' 
GROUP  BY i.id 
LIMIT  0, 20
```

So we are selecting the items in the database. The first join is for a picture (Items have multiple pictures but I only want one).

The next join is for favorite count. Each time a user favorites something it adds it to the table favorites with some info, so I am just trying to get the total number of favorites for that item.

Next up is the number of purchases for this item. Pretty much the same as favorites.

After that it is for comments. Again this is just like the purchases and favorites count.

The last join is to see if the logged in user (id 14) has favorited this item if not I use COALESCE to return 0.

Like I said this all works correctly but it does take a few seconds to load on a table of about 6700 items and about 180K rows in the purchases table for only loading 20 at a time (I do a scrolling/load similar to Facebook/Twitter). Indexes have been properly setup on all tables. Once this is complete/correct I would like to know how to limit results for purchases in the last seven days and order by number of purchases (num_buys).

EDIT: Results from EXPLAIN

[image]

Comment: first thing I would do is add an alias to each table and use the alias appropriately... it will make it a lot easier to read the query and speed up the helping process :)

Comment: pleasd add the result of `EXPLAIN <your query>`

Comment: You should ask in http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For things like this, where you will often want to many counts, comment count, favorite count, etc I generally would add a field for each to the items table, and just increment/decrement that field every time you insert/delete a record in the appropriate table. This way, when you go to query, you can just grab the totals that are already stored on the items table, and not have to do a bunch of subqueries to get these totals.

Comment: Added results from EXPLAIN

Comment: Do you only want to limit the purchase count to purchases within the last 7 days or only show items with purchases in the last 7 days?

Comment: Kinda both. I want to show all items that have been purchased in the past seven days and then order them by the number of purchases. purchases table has a column called date. I can put what ever format you need into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want the first picture (lowest id), and pictures are required, where as everything else is optional.

I guess you're doing subqueries because you think joining on uncorrelated subqueries (hitting the joined tables just once) will be faster than correlated subqueries or a plain JOIN. However, you end up having to lookup the records twice, and the second lookup (for the actual join) doesn't get to use an index because derived (temporary tables) don't have indexes.

Try normal JOINs:

```
SELECT items.*,
    p.file AS item_pic,
    COALESCE(i_f.id, 0) AS favorite_id,
    COUNT(f.item_id) AS favorite_count,
    COUNT(b.item_id) AS num_buys,
    COUNT(c.item_id) AS comment_count
FROM items i
STRAIGHT_JOIN item_pics p
  ON p.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN item_pics p2
  ON p2.item_id = i.id
  AND p2.id < p1.id
LEFT JOIN item_favorites f
  ON f.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN purchases b
  ON b.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN comments c
  ON c.item_id = i.id
LEFT JOIN item_favorites AS i_f 
    ON i_f.item_id  = i.id
    AND i_f.userid = '14'
WHERE p2.id IS NULL
GROUP BY i.id
LIMIT 20
```

The double join on pictures is an anti-join `WHERE p2.id IS NULL`, to retrieve the picture with the lowest `id`.

Comment: This does not work correctly. I have to end up cancelling the query and restarting MySQL as it consumes way to much resources. Here is the result of EXPLAIN http://www.hostingbytes.us/images/4/3511352.png

Comment: Are there more items than pictures? I changed the INNER JOIN to a STRAIGHT_JOIN to force it to scan items instead of pictures. Also, perhaps you typed something wrong with the join on comments because it shouldn't look like that. It should be using the index on comments.

Comment: There are more items then pictures by a couple thousand. I did find an issue with comments, had the wrong type for the index. INNER JOIN still causes it to hang but a STRAIGHT_JOIN brings it down to 2.5-3seconds. Which is what I want to improve. New EXPLAIN http://www.hostingbytes.us/images/4/4333434.png

Comment: Alright Marcus I was able to get the query down to 0.2 seconds. Thank you very much for that help. You think you can tackle the last seven days part?

Comment: All that is left is filtering for only items that have been bought in the last seven days and then order by number is purchases.